# MySQL update if exists else insert

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a table of archived values for each channel_id, but I also want to keep the current value for each channel_id available. I first tried to put it in a separate table, but using a union on the tables for each select query was impossibly slow (I made a view of the union of the two tables).

So I guess the best alternative is to keep it in the table of archived data, with an extra column to indicate if it is the current value?

My question is then, how do I add the current value to that table if a row does not exist with the same channel_id and current column equal to 1, and update it if it does exist?

I can't see a way to make a unique index that references both channel_id and current, since many channel_ids will have current = 0. So replace won't work. And update won't always work, because the row may not exist yet.

Is there a better solution? The table will have millions of entries and there will be hundreds of thousands of channel_ids.

EDIT

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
`date_time` decimal(26,6) NOT NULL,
`channel_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`connected` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
`current` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`,`date_time`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `current` (
`date_time` decimal(26,6) NOT NULL,
`channel_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`value` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`connected` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`channel_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

These are the tables I am currently dealing with. I would like to either find a good way to union these for queries (in which case the current column in the data table is not needed) or just use the data table and for a given channel_id find the one row for that channel_id that has current = 1 and if it exists, update it with a new date_time, value, status, and connected. If one doesn't exist, add it with those same values.

Answer (score 3):

Look at MySQL's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I don't think I can use that, because I can't see a way to create a unique id on channel_id and current.

Comment: And don't forget to reference the passed values, in the UPDATE statement, using the **VALUES(col_name)** accessor. I had to dig for an example of that the first time I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: I guess I swapped REPLACE and UPDATE in my question. I edited it to fix that. I don't think I can use REPLACE, because I can't see a way to create a unique index on channel_id and current, unless I create an entire new column of unique values.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can create a compound `UNIQUE` key.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON table_name ( `channel_id`, `current` );
```

Then, per the other answers, you can use either `REPLACE` or `ON DUPLICATE` to update. Obviously this is a terrible idea and reformation of the table should probably happen, but it will work.

Comment: But if there are many rows with the same channel_id and current = 0? How could I change the table?

Comment: You will likely have to not use something like `current` and instead use something real like `archived_date`. This means you will have to update the date, but there's little use you can do at this point.

Comment: All the values have a Unix time associated with them, including the current value. But sometimes the current value will become the archived value, and I wouldn't want to overwrite that.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should use `channel_id` and `unix_time` as the key then. You don't need ot update the time to use it, so long as it is always different.

Comment: But the new current value will have a new time, and the key has to be the same to update that row. And if the old current value becomes an archived value, I would overwrite it using just its channel_id and time.

Comment: Is there an IF ... THEN ... ELSE logic that I can use? Or maybe I can set the default for the current column to NULL. It looks like you can have unique ids with multiple NULL entries? Or is there a way to combine the two tables better?

Comment: The key has to be the same to update that particular row. Are you saying you want to update all items by channel id? Time should not matter in that regard, only if you are trying to update a particular record would you need time.

Comment: No, as a new value and time comes along for a given channel_id, I want to update the one row that contains the current value and time for that channel_id. Updating that row will be an update of the value and time. Some of the current times and corresponding values for that channel_id will become archived values for that channel_id, but not all of them.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something stuck deep in your mind. Update your question with schema and requirements.