# Mysql: insert if row doesn't exist, else update.. is there a simpler command?

Tags: mysql

Learning Mysql and having piles of questions...

I can achieve desired effect by simple:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT results SET user_id = '".$user_data[0]['user_id']."', logo_id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['logo_id'])."'");
$mysqli->query("UPDATE results SET result_tries = result_tries +1 WHERE logo_id = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['logo_id'])."' AND user_id = '".$user_data[0]['user_id']."'");
```

I've DB `unique check` on the table, so that logo_id and user_id should be unique. So if row exists first query fails, and the second update is executed..., But this feels kind of hack... Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please refer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030071/mysql-table-insert-if-not-exist-otherwise-update) on stack overflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557479/mysql-update-if-exists-else-insert

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
$user_id = $user_data[0]['user_id'];
$logo_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['logo_id']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO results (user_id, logo_id, result_tries) 
        VALUES ('$user_id', '$logo_id', 0)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE result_tries = result_tries + 1";

$mysqli->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

```
INSERT INTO assignment_status (user, assignment, status, note) VALUES (4, 7, 2, "My special note.")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=2, note="My special note."
```

Note that my primary key consists of 2 columns - `user` and `assignment` IDs...

Comment: You can create an index column on the tuple (assignment_id, user_id) and then the 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' will just work..

Comment: Updated. Thanks!