# Check if row exists before inserting or update

Tags: c#, mysql

```
public static void StoreGrid(ICAUploadDAO result)
{
      string queryString = "INSERT INTO Result (ModuleGrp, PEM, AdmNo, Name, ICA1, ICA2, ICA3, ICA4, ModuleCode) values ('" + @result.ModuleGrp + "','" + @result.PEM + "','" + @result.AdmNo + "','" + @result.Name + "','" + @result.ICA1 + "','" + @result.ICA2 + "','" + @result.ICA3 + "','" + @result.ICA4 + "','" + @result.ModuleCode + "')";

      string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnection;
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
}
```

I would like to check if the row already exists before inserting, if it exist then would like to update it. I would be very grateful if someone could kindly help me with this as I do not know how to go about it. Thank you so much

Comment: Which of your fields are the fields where you suppose that the record exist?

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: You can do this by c# code or by sql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL update if exists else insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557479/mysql-update-if-exists-else-insert)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`. But, you have to create unique index for combination of fields which you consider make record the same.

Unfortunately, not all databases support `REPLACE INTO`, but `MySQL` and `SQLite` do.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue a while back. Here's what I figured out:
http://remy.supertext.ch/2010/11/mysqlupdate-and-insert-if-not-exists/

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key) SELECT ?id, ‘page_title’  FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT meta_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = ?id AND meta_key = ‘page_title’);
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = ?page_title WHERE post_id = ?id AND meta_key = ‘page_title’;
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. I didn't know that way. (In fact i din't search) :)

Comment: this looks really heavy and prone to concurrency issues. Also, it will work slow unless you create compound index for list of fields mentioned in `UPDATE`. But, once such index is created, `REPLACE INTO` will work fast and is much shorter (and atomic to boot).

Comment: all fields actually, because i am trying to add data from excel spread sheet into database so hence if the record already exists it shouldnt store, currently since its an insert statement it just inserts everything. @kostasch.

Answer (score -1):

1. Simply write sql query to check the of row count(use primary key in where clause).
2. If count=0 then execute update query, if not execute insert query.

NOTE: use one SP to perform entire task rather than taking control to code level